# Url value is not passed to the tesl in selenium python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pytest-bdd

I am doing pytest-bdd with selenium python. I am doing BDD and page object model.
when i execute test, the url value is not passed to the browser.My actual code is

Browser instantiating file is as below

```
@pytest.fixture() 
def setup(browser): 
    if browser == 'firefox': 
        driver =
```

webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install(
))) return driver
else:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install(.           )))
return driver

```
def pytest_addoption(parser): 
    parser.addoption("--browser") 

@pytest.fixture() 
def browser(request): 
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")



config.ini
[common details]
Baseurl=www.https://google.com
```

Reading config.ini values in read_config.py file as below.

```
import configparser
# reading config file
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
file = "/Users/lgopal/PycharmProjects/Devices/Configuration/config.ini"
config.read(file)

class ReadConfig:
@staticmethod
def get_application_url():
    url = config.get("common details", "Baseurl")
    print(url)
    return url
```

page object for login is

```
class Login:
base_url = ReadConfig.get_application_url()
textbox_email_name = "email"
textbox_password_name = "password"
button_login_xpath = "//button[@type='submit']"

def __init__(self,driver):
    self.driver = driver

def set_user_name(self, username):
    self.driver.find_element(self.textbox_email_name).clear()
    self.driver.find_element(self.textbox_email_name).send_keys(username)

def set_password(self, password):
    self.driver.find_element(self.textbox_password_name).clear()
    self.driver.find_element(self.textbox_password_name).send_keys(password)

def click_login_button(self):
    self.driver.find_element(self.button_login_xpath).click()

def get_url(self):
    return self.driver.get(self.base_url)
```

The actual test page of step definition file using pytest-bdd is as below

```
import pytest
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then, parsers
from pytest_bdd.parsers import parse

import conftest
from pageObject.loginPage import Login


@when(parsers.parse('enter {username} and {password}'))
def test_user_credentials(username, password, setup):
    login = Login(setup)
    login.set_user_name(username)
    login.set_password(password)


@given("click login button.")
def test_click_login_button(setup):
    login = Login(setup)
    login.click_login_button()


@then("User should be directed to Home Page.")
def test_redirecting_to_home(setup):
    print("directed to home page")
```

in this case, it instantiate the browser, but the browser, but the url value is not passed.it exit s the test.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium driver.get(String url) expected url formats:"http://www.example.com" or "https://www.example.com"

change your url like "https://www.google.com/" and try again

Comment: any explanation why it would help the OP? not informative answers dont give anything to somebody who wants to learn

Comment: I tried, it did not work out...:-(

Comment: Is url printed succesfully to console? Where did you initialize your driver?

Comment: @pytest.fixture()
def setup(browser):
    if browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        return driver
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        return driver


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")


@pytest.fixture()
def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")

Comment: I am soryy i couldnt help. Maybe you can try update your webdriver manager version.
example link :https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/4.0.1/#use-with-chrome

Comment: No problem. Thanks a lot